# Executing the SQL file in Snowflake stored procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-stage

I'm trying to execute a SQL file in a stored procedure, but it is failing with an expression error.

Is there any way to execute a SQL file in a Snowflake stored procedure?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_stg_load()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE SQL 
AS
$$
    declare
        sql_stmt varchar(160000);
    begin
        sql_stmt := (select $1 from @eg_stage/stg_order_line.sql(file_format => 'my_csv_format'));
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :sql_stmt;
        return 'Success';
    end;
$$;
```

Here I'm trying to get the SQL statement from stage file and execute it. Is there any option to execute a SQL file via snowflake stored procedure?

Comment: Hi - please update your question with the error message you are getting. If you change your SP to return the SQL statement you want to execute, is the SQL what you expect?

Comment: Hi .. I’m storing the sql in a file(which is in internal stage)..querying the file to get sql statement ..so sp should execute the output of that stage query ..

Comment: Hi - that doesn’t seem to be a response to anything I put in my comment

Comment: Type of files supported in Stage are TYPE = { CSV | JSON | AVRO | ORC | PARQUET | XML }, So .Sql file if you try to load into internal stage it would fail unless you bring in the content of file (Sqls) in JSON format or XML format. As far as I know there is no option to execute .sql file in stored procedure.

Comment: It doesn't work like that. You want actually the resultset of the SELECT query to be executed by EXECUTE IMMEDIATE and in reality only the SELECT is executed. So what you actually need to do is use a [CURSOR](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/cursors) and fetch the result of the SELECT you have in a variable then execute the SQL contained in that variable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the question is interesting, however you have not shared with us the specific error.

I created a file with 2 sql statements:

```sql
select 1;
select 2;
```

And I created a copy of the question stored procedure:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_execute_sql()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE SQL 
AS
$$
    declare
        sql_stmt varchar(160000);
    begin
        sql_stmt := (select $1 from @fh_db.public.fhoffa_lit_stage/lala.sql);
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :sql_stmt;
        return 'Success';
    end;
$$;

call test_execute_sql();
```

It gave me the error `Uncaught exception of type 'EXPRESSION_ERROR' on line 5 at position 20 : Single-row subquery returns more than one row.`.

This because the file has 2 lines and I need to execute each one by one. A simple fix is to execute only the first one by adding a `limit 1`:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_execute_sql()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE SQL 
AS
$$
    declare
        sql_stmt varchar(160000);
    begin
        sql_stmt := (select $1 from @fh_db.public.fhoffa_lit_stage/lala.sql limit 1);
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :sql_stmt;
        return 'Success';
    end;
$$;

call test_execute_sql();
```

This returned `Success`.

If we want to get the result of the executed query:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_execute_sql()
RETURNS table(x number)
LANGUAGE SQL 
AS
$$
    declare
        sql_stmt varchar(160000);
        rs resultset;
    begin
        sql_stmt := (select $1 from @fh_db.public.fhoffa_lit_stage/lala.sql limit 1);
        rs := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :sql_stmt);
        return table(rs);
    end;
$$;

call test_execute_sql();
```

Which returns `1`.